# Rails 3 Custom Routes Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want something like this in my routes.rb. This isn't at all correct, but something like this:

```
match '/:scope/authenticate' => '%{:scope}_authentication#create'
```

So going to /users/authenticate would route to the create method in the users_authenticate controller.

What is the best way to do this in Rails 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not something I've done, but does this work?

```
resources :users_authenticate
resources :things_authenticate
resources :admins_authenticate
match "/:scope/authenticate" => redirect("%{scope}_authenticate/create")
```

Comment: not for me. I don't get an error, but this instead: You are being redirected.

Comment: Fair enough, like I say, I haven't tried it. I'll have a fiddle on Monday when I have my Rails dev environment to hand if you haven't had an answer first.

Comment: How about if you put a `/` at the start of the redirect string?

Comment: Weird, it works now on another app. You can also `do match "/:scope/authenticate", :to => redirect("%{scope}_authenticate/create")`